# Split or regex command to pull the task name and lastresult from text file

Tags: vbscript

```
TaskName=YY_EF LastRunTime="3/14/2016 10:30:00 PM" LastResult=1
TaskCommand="C:\Windows\scripts\Tasks\FC_CREATE" TaskState=Enabled
StartTime="10:30:00 PM" RunTime="00:15:00" Days="Every 1 day(s)"
```

'read a Log

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"). 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\" & _ "sample.txt", ForReading). 
WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Job Records" Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True.
  strLine = objtextFile.ReadLine
  If inStr(strLine, " ") Then.
    arrRecord = split(strLine, " ").  WScript.Echo vbCrLf & arrRecord(0) & " " & arrRecord(4).
    'WScript.Echo arrRecord(4).
    i = i + 1.
  End If.
Loop.
Wscript.Echo vbCrLf & "Number of records read: " & i.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely does what you want:

```
Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\scripts\" & _ "sample.txt", ForReading)

WScript.Echo vbCrLf & "Job Records"

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
  strLine = objtextFile.ReadLine
  If inStr(strLine, " ") Then
    arrRecord = split(strLine, " ")
    If (UBound(arrRecord, 1) > 3) Then
        If (Left(arrRecord(0), 8) = "TaskName") Then
            WScript.Echo "TaskName = " & Mid(arrRecord(0), 10)
            WScript.Echo "LastResult = " & Mid(arrRecord(4), 12)
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  End If
Loop
Wscript.Echo vbCrLf & "Number of records read: " & i
```